# SQL: how to make multiple COUNT/MAX

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `medic_appointment` with the following fields: `datetime_diagnosis` (`DATETIME` type) and `diagnosis`. I need to perform a query that will show me the `YEAR_MONTH` which had the most occurrence of each disease.

I am currently at this point:

```
SELECT disease , COUNT(*) AS frequency , 
       EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetime_diagnosis) AS interval
FROM medic_appointment
GROUP BY disease , interval
```

Which results in the following example table:

```
disease    frequency   interval
--------   ---------   --------
disease1   5           201609
disease1   8           201610
disease1   22          201611
disease1   1           201612
disease2   7           201611
```

I am trying to do something like this: using the query mentioned above, increment it in a way that it will select the highest frequency number and return me the interval and disease fields, then group by disease...but it is not working this way and i just cannot find another way to figure it out. Not sure if this is the best option.

edit: expected result:

```
disease    frequency   interval
--------   ---------   --------
disease1   22          201611
disease2   7           201611
```

Comment: Providing expected result in words is much complicate to understand. Provide expected resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT disease, frequency, interval
FROM (
  SELECT disease, frequency, interval,
         @rnk := IF(@dis = disease, @rnk + 1,
                    IF(@dis := disease, 1, 1)) AS rnk  
  FROM (
     SELECT disease, COUNT(*) AS frequency, 
            EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetime_diagnosis) AS interval
     FROM medic_appointment
     GROUP BY disease, interval) AS t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0, @dis := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY disease, frequency DESC) AS x
WHERE x.rnk = 1
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error. MySQL points the syntax error around the @dis := disease, 1,1)...i am still trying to understand this code (have never seen something similar before), so it may take a while :( but thanks for showing this new way of working with SQL codes

Comment: Still no success :( keeps telling me there is some syntax error around 4th line (starts with @rnk := ...

Comment: @Rodrigo `@dis` variable was incorrectly initialized. Please try once more.